# SQL Server: Splitting string by '/' and put each split element into a different column

Tags: sql, sql-server, split, sql-server-2000

I have a table on an external site that I need to copy to a local DB, but with some transformations. One of the columns I have to heavily modify is called product_url. The URL is in the form site.com\category\sub-category\brand\model#.

The table in my local db will have 4 columns to hold this data. They will be category, sub-category, brand and model#. So, I will have to first trim the site.com (I did this using truncate), but now I have to parse \category\sub-category\brand\model#

I found a UDF from SO that I think will help out. Here it is:

```
create function dbo.SplitString 
    (
        @str nvarchar(4000), 
        @separator char(1)
    )
    returns table
    AS
    return (
        with tokens(p, a, b) AS (
            select 
                1, 
                1, 
                charindex(@separator, @str)
            union all
            select
                p + 1, 
                b + 1, 
                charindex(@separator, @str, b + 1)
            from tokens
            where b > 0
        )
        select
            p-1 zeroBasedOccurance,
            substring(
                @str, 
                a, 
                case when b > 0 then b-a ELSE 4000 end) 
            AS s
        from tokens
      )
    GO
```

Now I am having trouble using this function. Probably due to my lack of experience with UDF's.

Here is what I have now:

```
select s from
dbo.SplitString(select substring(product_url, 8, len(product_url)) 
            from Products, '/')
where zeroBasedOccurance=0 AS Category
```

This is obviously not even syntactically correct.

I am wondering if I am going about this the best way. I am not yet much of a DBA, so I am having a hard time wrapping my head around this issue. I just need to figure out how to apply this UDF ~4 times for each row in the product_url table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure about your function, but here is mine:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.FN_PARSENAME(@chunk VARCHAR(4000), @delimiter CHAR(1), @index INT )
RETURNS VARCHAR(1000)
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE
    @curIndex INT = 0,
    @pos INT = 1,
    @prevPos INT = 0,
    @result VARCHAR(1000)

WHILE @pos > 0
BEGIN

    SET @pos =  CHARINDEX(@delimiter, @chunk, @prevPos);

    IF(@pos > 0)
    BEGIN -- Characters between position and previous position
        SET @result = SUBSTRING(@chunk, @prevPos, @pos-@prevPos)
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN -- Last Delim
        SET @result = SUBSTRING(@chunk, @prevPos, LEN(@chunk))
    END

    IF(@index = @curIndex)
    BEGIN
        RETURN @result
    END

    SET @prevPos = @pos + 1
    SET @curIndex = @curIndex + 1;
END
RETURN '' -- Else Empty
END
```

You call it as such:
    `SELECT Address_Line1 = dbo.fn_Parsename(Merged,'|', 0)
    FROM Table`

Wherein Merged is the field that is delimited, the '|' is the delimiter, so you would make it '\', and the 0 is which portion of the string you want, 0 being the first, on up.

For your example it would be:

```
SELECT category = dbo.fn_Parsename(product_url,'\', 1)
     , sub-category = dbo.fn_Parsename(product_url,'\', 2)
     , brand = dbo.fn_Parsename(product_url,'\', 3)
     , model# = dbo.fn_Parsename(product_url,'\', 4)
FROM Table
```

Or maybe 0-3 depending.

I'm pretty confident I adapted that from something I found, perhaps even on SO, but I can't recall who would deserve credit.

Comment: excellent! Thanks for the solution. One note for anyone else who comes across this and shares the misfortune of having to use SQL 200m0, you can't declare variables with default values. So just set them after declaring.

Comment: Ah good point, hopefully that's a very small population of people. If that's all you need, kindly accept this as the answer.

Comment: We can only hope. I plan to, just need to wait for it to allow me to.