# SQL Split Comma Seperated Strings Into Multiple Columns

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, csv

I am newish to SQL to please excuse any ignorance. I have a table, called 'temp' that contains one Field, (called Field1) with rows and rows of long comma seperated strings, thus:

```
Temp table
Field1
ABC123,1,Z,some text
ABC456,1,q,some text
ABC789,1,r,some text
ABC111,1,y,some text
```

I then have a another table, called Detail, with 4 headings. So how do I insert the above from the temp table to the temp table to look like this:

```
Detail Table
Field1          Field 2    Field 3          Field 4
ABC123         1             Z                 some text
ABC456         1             q                 some text 
ABC789          1            r                  some text
ABC111         1            y                 some text
```

I will then be using reporting reporting services to report on the detail table.  Do I need to call a function?  I've been reading up and some people are saying an XML function is better?  All my other bits of code is in a SP so how do I call it from here?

Thank you in advance for any help.

Regards,

Michael

Comment: You don't specify an RDBMS, but there are multiple duplicates of this question, all shown on the right-hand side:  SQL Server (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9589282/converting-comma-delimited-string-to-multiple-columns-in-sql-server?rq=1 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16722307/sql-server-splitting-string-by-and-put-each-split-element-into-a-different?rq=1), MySQL (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6823924/split-column-string-into-multiple-columns-strings?rq=1), etc....

Comment: Why dont you put it into .csv format and pipe it into a table using SSIS - Does it have to be held within a temporary table?

Comment: This question does not show any research effort. It is important to **do your homework**. Tell us what you found and ***why*** it didn't meet your needs. This demonstrates that you've taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer. [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask).

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQL Server 2008 how to split a comma-separated value to columns](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10581772/sql-server-2008-how-to-split-a-comma-separated-value-to-columns)

Comment: I had to put it in a temp table to start as the file is coming from a legacy system whereby some of the fields have double quotes and some do not.  SQL specifies that either none or all of the values in a data field are enclosed in quotation marks (""), so I first import into a temp table, then cleanup to remove the " ".

Answer (score 0):

The database you are using makes a big difference.  Here is an example of how to do it in MySQL:

```
insert into detail(field1, field2, field3, field4)
    select substring_index(field1, 1),
           reverse(substring_index(reverse(substring_index(field1, 2)))),
           reverse(substring_index(reverse(substring_index(field1, 3)))),
           reverse(substring_index(reverse(substring_index(field1, 4))))
    from tempTable t
```

The complex expression for the 2-4 fields is just a way of extracting the nth item from the list.